# Selenium Server with Chrome using Codeception RunProcess issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm looking at using Selenium Server with Chrome to doing browser acceptance testing with the Codeception framework.  Working locally on a Windows 10 machine.

My acceptance.suite.yml:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester

extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunProcess:
            - php -S 127.0.0.1:4444
            - java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar

modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://mysite.dev/'
            browser: chrome
            host: localhost
            port: 4444
            window_size: 1024x768
            restart: true
        - Asserts
        - \Helper\AcceptanceInternal
```

Running my tests from the commandline, it starts selenium, but the tests fail with this error:

```
AcceptanceInternal Tests (12) ------------------------------

  [RunProcess] Starting php -S 127.0.0.1:4444
  [RunProcess] Starting java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
1) ProductControllerCest: Cannot view index without logging in
 Test  tests/acceptanceInternal/Controller/Internal/ProductControllerCest.php:notLoggedInIndex



  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException] JSON decoding of remote response failed.
Error code: 4
The response: '\<!doctype html>\<html>\<head>\<title>404 Not Found\</title>\<style>
body { background-color: #fcfcfc; color: #333333; margin: 0; padding:0; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: normal; background-color: #9999cc; min-height:2em; line-height:2em; border-bottom: 1px inset black; margin: 0; }
h1, p { padding-left: 10px; }
code.url { background-color: #eeeeee; font-family:monospace; padding:0 2px;}
\</style>
\</head>\<body>\<h1>Not Found\</h1>\<p>The requested resource \<code class="url">/wd/hub/session\</code> was not found on this server.\</p>\</body>\</html>'
```

However if I visit in the browser, I see selenium:
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html

Any suggestions about what might be going wrong here?

Comment: `4444` is dedicated for selenium. You probably need to change the one of the ports

Comment: Ended up going a different route, spinning up a Selenium standalone chrome container and using that, and it worked out with my setup.  
https://robotninja.com/blog/introduction-using-selenium-docker-containers-end-end-testing/